# Syntax Error trying to return row number from database

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, row-number

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY id), x, y, id
FROM coordonnees
ORDER BY id
```

I'm trying to return the row number of each row (the table named `coordonnees` with 3 columns: `id`, `x`, `y`), but this code doesn't work

The error is:

> Syntax error near '(ORDER BY id), x, y, id

on database : MYSQL 5.7.9

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Not all databases support `row_number()`.

Comment: The syntax [is correct](http://rextester.com/HJVI30138). Maybe the DBMS you are using simply does not support modern SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I will try thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, MySQL 5.7 doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER()`. However, I found a novel solution that will emulate it at [this site](https://preilly.me/2011/11/11/mysql-row_number/).

```
SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value=c.id,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
       ,c.x
       ,c.y
       ,c.id
       ,@prev_value := c.id
FROM coordonnees c,
    (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
    (SELECT @prev_value := -1) y
ORDER BY c.id
```

There are a few caveats, though:

- The `@row_num` variable must be set before the `@prev_value` variable.
- The first field in the `ORDER BY` must be the field that you are partitioning by.
- The default value assigned to the `@prev_value` variable must not exist in the partition by field.